# How do I import Modernizr in React

Tags: reactjs, modernizr

I'm trying to detect whether the browser supports window.addEventListener in a create-react-app. I followed the instructions on the modernizr website and have created a modernizr.min.js file with only the single feature test I want. I can't import modernizr since it's not a module. The minified code is hard to read so I'm not sure where I'd modify it to make this a module.

So how do I actually use Modernizr in the javascript of react app?

Comment: you can import the script directly to your `public/index.html` and call the method from your code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Under your `public/index.html` just import the script directly

**public/index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"/>
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />


    ...


    <!-- add your scripts here -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.8.3/modernizr.min.js"></script>
    <!-- -->


    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
```

And then in your code just call it directly

i.e. in **App.jsx**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  render() {

    // add this to not trigger eslint no-undef
    /* global Modernizr */
    console.log(Modernizr);
    // do your checking with Modernizr
    if (Modernizr.awesomeNewFeature) {
      // do your stuff here
    } 

 ...
```

If you're using **typescript**, you need to declare the module/object first in the beginning of the typescript file that will use Modernizr, i.e.

```
declare const Modernizr:any;
```

or extend the `Window` interface, i.e.

```
declare global {
  interface Window {
    Modernizr:any     
  }
}
```

and call Modernizr under `window` interface like so

```
window.Modernizr.someFeature
```

Comment: I was hoping to use a smaller subset of Modernizr since I don't need all of the other feature checks. But I will test this tonight and if it works for me, I'll mark it as the answer.

Comment: @LeeO. you can use any subset of Modernizr as you like, i.e. when you import the scripts in the html `<script type="text/javascript" src="{your_js_file_url_here}"></script>` and then you can use the lib/object as normal in your react javascript

Comment: I had actually tried this once but my build failed because of the eslint error. I thought it wasn't working not that eslint was wrong. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @LeeO. no problem, to avoid [no-undef](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-undef) eslint error, you'll have to add a comment to declare the global module `/* global Modernizr */`

Comment: @van : I followed the above steps, I am getting ./node_modules/modernizr/lib/build.js Module not found: Can't resolve 'generate'. Am i missing anything ? do I need to use webpack-modernizr-loader too ?

Comment: with customized modernizr just directly import using the <script> tag upstream (I put it in `_document`) and place the custom js file in your public folder. I accessed Modernizr in my index.tsx with this code: ```if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
      window.Modernizr = Modernizr;  // proceed to test for each feature```

Comment: this no longer seems to work - I get a 404 error when trying to call it